# Order of default and non-default arguments

Tags: python, argument-passing

In Python, I understand that default arguments come at the end and that non-default arguments cannot follow a default argument. That is fine. Like for example:

```
>>> def foo(x=0, y):
        return x, y
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

That is OK as expected.

However, what about the case when I want that the *first argument should be a default one*? Like for example, as is apparent from the above code, `x` has to be the first argument and it should have a default value of 0.

Is it possible to do this? I am asking because even in the `range` function, I am guessing it is something like this:

```
def range(start=0, end):
    pass
```

So how is this done and if it is not possible, how is this implemented by `range`? Note that I am insisting on the first argument to be default, that is the entire point. I am using `range` as an example because it fits my problem perfectly. Of course one could implement `range` as `def range(end, start=0)`, but that is not the point.

Comment: As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why). 

People might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it: `range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `range` is C code which can do this slightly better. Anyways, you can do this:

```
def range(start, stop=None):
    if stop is None: # only one arg, treat stop as start ...
        stop = start
        start = 0
    ...
```

and document the function accordingly.

Comment: Nearly identical to my answer, but clearer and five minutes earlier.  So, +1.

Comment: Might want to add a `step` argument for consistency with built-in.

Comment: is there a constructor or a way to raise the *same* `TypeError: <xxx> takes no keyword arguments` that eg. `range(start=1)` would raise? Or what about the *'... takes ... arguments ... given'* TypeError? Can I raise the same one? I ask because I do *not* wish to *mimic* it if it's possible to raise the exact one. In the unlikely case python make a change in the message (like some custom localized build or something) I wish mine would change accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple approaches. The first would be to switch the arguments in the function, if some of the arguments are "None". That would work like this.

```
def range1(value, end=None):
    if end == None:
        end = value
        value = 0
    return _generate_range_values(value, end)
```

The other primary method would be to have your function get a list of all arguments it receives. Then it can decide what to do, based on the number of arguments.

```
def range2(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        start = 0
        end = int(args[0])
    elif len(args) == 2:
        start = int(args[0])
        end = int(args[1])
    return _generate_range_values(start, end)
```

The third would be to encourage users to pass named arguments to your function, which makes the order less important.

```
def range3(end, start=0):
    return _generate_range_values(start, end)
```

Then users would call it with the named start argument when they wanted something besides 0. (Although the named argument would not be required, it keeps the code clear.

```
for i in range3(55, start=12)
```

Comment: +1 Even though I don't understand why did you felt the need to use `int()` on `args[x]` in `range2()` but not in the others. It's not necessary (although it does allow that version to accept floating point and string arguments like `3.14` and `"42"`).

Comment: Looking back, I'm not sure why I used int() in one of the examples and not others. The builtin range() function will raise an error if it gets anything besides integer arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It is not implemented by `range`. You can use `*args` or `**args` and treat the tuple or the dict as you want. For example:

```
def f(*args):
  if len(args) == 1:
     print "assuming the first is default"
  elif len(args) == 2:
     print "two arguments were passed"
  else:
     print "Complaining"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the Exceptions yourself if you really want that

```
def Range(start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        raise AttributeError("end value not specified")
     pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the code for range, but I'm certain it performs this kind of trick:

```
def range(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    ...
```

**edit:** Code corrected per martineau's comment.

Answer (score 0):

For a function with the first default value parameter to be followed by other parameters:

```
def fn(first=value, *rest):
    # code
```

e.g.:

```
def fn(first=1, *rest):
    print(first)

fn()
fn(11, 2, 3)
>>>
1
11
```