# the strange arguments of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, range

The range function in python3 takes three arguments. Two of them are optional. So the argument list looks like:

[start], stop, [step]

This means (correct me if i'm wrong) there is an optional argument before a non-optional argument. But if i try to define a function like this i get this:

```
>>> def foo(a = 1, b, c = 2):
    print(a, b, c)
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Is this something I can't do as a 'normal' python user or can i somehow define such a function? Of course i could do something like

```
def foo(a, b = None, c = 2):
    if not b:
        b = a
        a = 1
```

but for example the help function would then show strange informations. So i really want to know if it's possible do define a function like the built-in `range`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4137838/568777

Comment: As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why). 

People might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it: `range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`range()` takes 1 positional argument and two optional arguments, and *interprets* these arguments differently depending on how many arguments you passed in.

If only *one* argument was passed in, it is assumed to be the `stop` argument, otherwise that first argument is interpreted as the start instead.

In reality, `range()`, [coded in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44467e8ea4cea390b0718702291b4cfe8ddd67ed/Objects/rangeobject.c#L71-L122), takes a variable number of arguments. You could emulate that like this:

```
def foo(*params):
    if 3 < len(params) < 1:
        raise ValueError('foo takes 1 - 3 arguments')
    elif len(params) == 1
        b = params[0]
    elif:
        a, b = params[:2]
    c = params[2] if len(params) > 2 else 1
```

but you could also just swap arguments:

```
def range(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
```

Comment: Your final example doesn't work. TypeError: range() does not take keyword arguments

Comment: @RobSmallshire: The final example is a *python replacement* for `range()`. I used keyword arguments to emulate the optional arguments that `range()` takes; the alternative would be to use a `*args` catch-all argument and parse up to 2 values from that, but that gets a lot more verbose. That's the first sample in my answer.

Comment: @RobSmallshire: The OP tried to emulate the `range()` behaviour with keyword arguments, the second part is to illustrate how you could implement the behaviour (accept between 1 and 3 positional arguments) by using keyword arguments, *in python code*.

Comment: So, this is only because the C-coded version of this takes `*params` instead of actually defining arguments...but why would they code it like that? I don't see a reason to use `*params` over arguments, *especially* if the function will return an error if the length of your params is greater than 3. Just seems like very sloppy coding...is it because it's faster? To me it should have been coded as `range(PyObject *stop, PyObject *start, PyObject *step)` and not deal with this problem. Just seems like a very strange decision to me...

Comment: @CoreyLevinson: no, because then you'd have to always specify the start and step values. The Python core developers made an explicit choice to support both `range(stop)` and `range(start, stop)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why would you always have to specify the start and step values? You can just have in the C function, `if (start == NULL && step == NULL)` as one of the first lines in the function, right? This will solve the `TypeError: range() takes no keyword arguments` problem that @eumiro cites in the answer below.

Comment: @CoreyLevinson: Why is not taking keyword arguments a problem? Most built-in types don't take keyword arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because I wanted to write `range(start=0,stop=10,step=2)` to emphasize the start, stop, and step sizes for anyone who saw my code and was unfamiliar with Python. It's a weird quirk that most built-in types don't take keyword arguments in my opinion. In fact the `TypeError` was the reason I found this StackOverflow post! I have to use `np.linspace` to solve my problem now, which is fine, but I just think it's kind of annoying I couldn't use `range` with keywords.

Answer (score 17):

`range` does not take keyword arguments:

```
range(start=0,stop=10)
TypeError: range() takes no keyword arguments
```

it takes 1, 2 or 3 positional arguments, they are evaluated according to their number:

```
range(stop)              # 1 argument
range(start, stop)       # 2 arguments
range(start, stop, step) # 3 arguments
```

i.e. it is not possible to create a range with defined `stop` and `step` and default `start`.

Comment: is there no way to make the `range` function take arguments without writing dummy functions or something...?

Comment: Found an answer to my own question:

`range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())`

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(first, second=None, third=1):
     if second is None:
         start, stop, step = 0, first, 1
     else:
         start, stop, step = first, second, third
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know by now the real answer is that `range` is a C function which for some reason does not have the same rules of python (would be nice to know why).

People might hate me for suggesting this but I've being doing this for range since I have a terrible memory of what the order of things are. Imo this shouldn't be a problem so I'm fixing it:

```
range(*{'start':0,'stop':10,'step':2}.values())
```

the reason I made it a one liner is because I don't want to have to define a range function that needs to be defined everywhere or imported everywhere. This is pure python.