# Emulating Built-In Optional Arguments in Python3

Tags: python

I want to design optional arguments in a manner like how the built-in slice() operates:

slice(stop) or slice(start, stop[, step])

I know that I can make a function as follows:

```
_no_value = object()
my_slice(start=None, stop=_no_value, step=None):
    if stop is _no_value:
        raise ValueError('stop needs supplied value')
```

But then I would need to call it like my_slice(stop=val) rather than my_slice(val) which is what I want to emulate the built-in slice().

Comment: `range` and `slice` do tricky things. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875232/4014959

Comment: Note, `slice` doesn't *take* keyword arguments. It essentialyl works off the number of arguments you provided. So if you provide one argument, it assumes it means stop, if you provide two... it assumes it's start-stop etc etc. So the signature would be `my_slice(*args)` with logic to handle the cases inside

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.