# Why can't we assign a Default argument in Generators?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I was working with Generators in Python, and I have tried the Default argument in the generator's declaration.

It was not allowing the Default argument and Shown an Error.

The Question is : Why ?

#### Generate the Random numbers N times

```
import random

def print_random(low = 0,high , n):

    for i in range(n):
        yield random.rand(low,high)
```

Expected to Execute without any Error.
But, The Error given :

`SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. Putting the default arguments first gives a a generator signature like `def print_random(high, n, low = 0):` which is counterintutitive. OP is clearly trying for a signature like, say, `range()` where a call to `range(10)` means the same as a call to `range(0, 10)`.

Comment: @BoarGules Then this is appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875232/476

Answer (score 0):

In Python, default arguments must be placed after non-defaults. You shoud change your code like this:

```
import random

def print_random(high, n, low = 0):
    for i in range(n):
        yield random.rand(low,high)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).